# Cannot access private member from within class in C++?

Tags: c++, arraylist

SO I am trying to teach myself data structures in C++. To do so, I made an ArrayList class with a member variable arrayData with type int* and a get method to access values from that pointer. I come from a Java background and C++ OOP is sorta strange, especially with the separation of header and source files. At compile, I get, "error: 'int* ArrayList::arrayData' is not a static data member of 'class ArrayList'". I marked them with ArrayList:: to make them members of ArrayList, so why does this not mark them as such? Thank you so much if you can point me in the direction of how to access my variable.
ArrayList.cpp:

```
#include "ArrayList.h"

ArrayList::ArrayList(int size) {
  arrayData = new int[size];

}

ArrayList::~ArrayList() {
  delete arrayData;
}
int* ArrayList::get(int index) {
  return (*(this.arrayData))[index];
}
int* ArrayList::arrayData;
```

ArrayList.h:

```
#define ARRAYLIST_H_

class ArrayList {
public:
    ArrayList(int size);
    ~ArrayList();
    int get(int index);
private:
    int* arrayData;
};
#endif /* ARRAYLIST_H_ */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

int* ArrayList::arrayData;

In the source file makes no sense. Compiler thinks you're referencing a static variable of ArrayList (because you've prepended with the class name). Remove this line.

You will be able to access arrayData from the other methods.

Also, use `std::unique_ptr<int>` instead of the raw pointer. Then your memory is guaranteed to be automatically released after use.

Comment: Oh, so in c++ variabke declaration only has to exist in the header file?

Comment: Yes, except for static variables (hence your compile error). The class::variable syntax is for static variables of a class, because being static they cannot be accessed via an instance of the object.

Comment: Okay so, when trying to access arrayData once I fixed that line and removed the static modifier for get(int), it says arrayData was not declared within scope. Is it not object scope?

Comment: Where are you accessing it from? Btw your header says get() returns an int, but your source implementation says int*. These need to match. Also, make arrayData a std::vector<int>, it'll make life easier.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors here.

First, your ArrayList.h include guards are incorrect.

```
#ifndef ARRAYLIST_H_
#define ARRAYLIST_H_

class ArrayList {
public:
    ArrayList(int size);
    ~ArrayList();
    int get(int index);
private:
    int* arrayData;
};
#endif /* ARRAYLIST_H_ */
```

Next, Your int ArrayList::get declaration and definition are inconsistent.  There isn't a need for the int* ArrayList::arrayData; in your C++ file as well.

```
#include "ArrayList.h"

ArrayList::ArrayList(int size) {
  arrayData = new int[size];

}

ArrayList::~ArrayList() {
  delete arrayData;
}
int ArrayList::get(int index) {
  return arrayData[index];
}
```